# "Within semantics" for proximity queries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geospatial

I have defined a "2dsphere" index for field `loc` in collection `c`:

```
db.c.createIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } )
```

I have the following document in `c` collection. It is a line from [40, 5] to [41, 6]:

```
db.c.insert({"name": "myLine", "loc": { type: "LineString", coordinates: [ [ 40, 5 ], [ 41, 6 ] ] }})
```

Using the [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near) operator, a proximity query centered at [40, 5] with a very small radius matches (i.e. it returns the document):

```
db.c.find({
  loc: {
    $near: {
      $geometry: {
         type: "Point" ,
         coordinates: [ 40, 5 ]
       },
       $maxDistance: 0.0001,
    } 
  } 
})
```

The same for the other point in the line:

```
db.c.find({
  loc: {
    $near: {
      $geometry: {
         type: "Point" ,
         coordinates: [ 41, 6 ]
       },
       $maxDistance: 0.0001,
    } 
  } 
})
```

Thus, it seems that `$near` has "intersect" semantics: if some of the points of the geometry is within the proximity region, then query matches.

However, I wonder if it is some way of specifying that *all* points of the geometry have to be within the proximity region. In other words, a semantic similar to the one of the [`$geoWithin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#op._S_geoWithin) operator (which as far as I know can be used only when the query can be expressed as a GJSON, i.e. not suitable for circles).

After looking to the [geo spacial queries section in the MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/), I haven't found an answer...

**EDIT:** It has been mentioned that this question could be a duplicate of [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784631/will-a-mongo-near-return-documents-for-which-any-point-in-a-multipoint-is-withi). However, I don't think so, given that the referred question is asking about $near/$geoNear/$geoWithin operators, while I'm asking for a solution to the problem of "within semantics" in proximity queries (no matter if one of these operators or other mechanism is used to solve the problem). In addition, the referred question is about MultiPoint while my example is based on LineString (although maybe this is a secondary aspect).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will a Mongo $near return documents for which any point in a MultiPoint is within range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784631/will-a-mongo-near-return-documents-for-which-any-point-in-a-multipoint-is-withi)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but maybe a subset... Thus, let's see what SOF community thinks (if the result if to close this question due to duplication, it is ok with me :)

Comment: Looking closely, I don't think is the same question, as the referred one is asking about $near/$geoNear/$geoWithin operators, while I'm asking for a solution to the problem of "within semantics" in proximity queries (no matter if one of these operators or other mechanism is used to solve the problem). In addition, the referred question is about MultiPoint while my example is based on LineString (although maybe this is a secondary aspect). I'd try to clarify in the body of the question post.

Comment: Of course it's the same question, or at least the same answer. You are asking "can i do this", to which the answer is no and an explanation is given why for each case.